# how to replace bvector header for version g++5

Tags: c++, ubuntu, installation, g++

An algorithm that use a predefined header, this algorithm is old 2005 and I think it is implemented for old g++4.2.1, because in g++5 you can't find `bvector.h` header
In older version you can find it in `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/bvector.h`, how to obtain this header, or with which header it is replaced in new g++ version, and it generate error:

```
#include<bvector.h>
#include<iostream>
 .....
```

how to replace it?

Answer (score 0):

Look in your old version - you must have gcc4.2.1 with this header if your code ever compiled - and see what it does.

Does it provide a typedef for `vector<bool>`? Just port your code to use `vector<bool>` directly. If you have to replicate the typedef, don't try adding it to `namespace std`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from this [libstdc++ patch](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2004-02/msg00303.html) the old typedef was similar to this:

```
typedef std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool> > bit_vector;
```

which should be straight forward to replicate, it looks like part of this patch was eventual removal as we can see from the [follow-up](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2004-02/msg00321.html) which matches the fact that it is now unavailable.

This old [gcc bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18188) also recommends replacing it with `vector<bool>`.